# Sorting an array to be ascending order

Tags: php

I'm trying to sort my array in ascending order. My array is kind of working, what I mean by that is I'm getting

```
    P1
    P10
    P11
    P12
    P2
    P3
    P4
    P40
    P41
    P42
    P5
```

but what I would like is this

```
    P1
    P2
    P3
    P4
    P5
    P10
    P11
    P12
    P40
    P41
    P42
```

Here is my code

```
    $sortedItems = $this->product->getCategoryCodes();
    sort($sortedItems);
```

This is what I get when I echo out my $sortedItems

```
array:2 [
    "P1" => Modules\...\Product{
        -name: "Product 1"
        -description: "A description"
    }
    "P2" => Modules\...\Product{
        -name: "Product 2"
        -description: "A description 2"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it. This is the code I used

```
$sortedItems = $this->product->getCategoryCodes();
ksort($sortedItems, SORT_NATURAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [natsort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort), or usual sort functions (`sort`, `asort`, `rsort` etc.) with parameter [SORT_NATURAL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)

e.g.

```
  $a = ['P1','P10','P11','P12','P12','P13', 'P4', 'P40', 'P41', 'P42', 'P5'];
  natsort($a);
  print_r($a); // maintains keys

  // OR

  sort($a, SORT_NATURAL);
  print_r($a); // reassigns keys
```

**edit**

if you want to sort the array by keys then use [ksort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) with SORT_NATURAL as the second parameter.

```
<?php
  $a = ['P1' => 'Something', 'P10' => 'Anything', 'P2' => 'Nothing'];
  ksort($a, SORT_NATURAL);
  print_r($a); // (    [P1] => Something    [P2] => Nothing    [P10] => Anything    )
```

Comment: I'm getting this `Object of class could not be converted to string`

Comment: That's becasue your array contains not strings but objects

Comment: I've updated my question to include what I get when I echo out `$sortedItems`

Comment: @Aurilie there is something wrong: key "P1" appears two times in the array output. So, you want to order this array by keys? I've expanded the answer

Comment: sorry that was just a typo. I adjusted my question.